# How to exclude files from git id expansion

Tags: git

I am using git-svn, and am using the `.git/info/attributes` file to, sort-of, emulate the svn $Id$ tag. So I have the following in my `.git/info/attributes`:

```
#*.awk      ident # disabled due to a/b/c/mdoc2man.awk
*.c        ident
```

The problem is that I need to disable ident for *all* awk files, when actually, I only want to disable it for `a/b/c/mdoc2man.awk`. I have tried using the negative pattern, but get this warning:

```
warning: Negative patterns are ignored in git attributes
Use '\!' for literal leading exclamation.
```

Are there any other options available?

Comment: Given how few views this got, I am going to assume that no-one has a better idea than mine below, and will accept this answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my particular case, my top level directory only had a few choices, so, since I know that I wanted to exclude, effectively, all files under a, and I only wanted the expansion to occur on all files under `other_dir`, then I changed the pattern to be:

```
other_dir/**/*.awk      ident
*.c                     ident
```